# making gridster margins collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gridster

I'm using `gridster`  to create dynamic grids with 5 pixel margin space between widgets.
but it creates 10 pixel margins! ([see this](http://jsfiddle.net/wMC9v/))
actually it adds margin for both neighbor widgets (left & right widgets)
How can i make gridster to collapse margins so the gap between two neighbor widgets be 5 pixel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/d6BWD/

```
  gridster = $(".gridster > ul").gridster({
      widget_margins: [2.5, 2.5],
      widget_base_dimensions: [100, 100]
  }).data('gridster');
```

5 + 5 = 10

2.5 + 2.5 = 5

Comment: Then you are asking for an api that does not exist. You will need to fork gridster.